# angularjs component with dynamic templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is it possible to create a AngularJS Component with a dynamic templateUrl?
Means I want to inject a service into the Component that gives me a base path to the template:

i.e.: templateUrl: configuration.baseScriptPath + '...html'

It is possible with a Directive, but how to do this with a Component?

```
angular.module('runtime')
    .component('textInput', {

        templateUrl: /*configuration.baseScriptPath + */'fd/components/text_input_instance.html',
        controller: [
            '$scope', '$element', 'focusInputGroup', 'configuration',
            function ($scope, $element, focusInputGroup, configuration) {
```

Comment: If it is working in directive, it should work in Component as well because 'templateUrl' property is not modified..

Comment: I want to inject configuration so that it is useable in templateUrl.

Comment: Could you share your component code?

Comment: Just added. The comment shows what I want to accomplish, but how can configuration be injected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of templateUrl you can use template and `ng-include`, like this:

```
angular.module('runtime')
    .component('textInput', {

        template: '<div ng-include="getTemplate()">',
        controller: [
            '$scope', '$element', 'focusInputGroup', 'configuration',
            function ($scope, $element, focusInputGroup, configuration) {

           $scope.getTemplate = function () {
               return configuration.baseScriptPath + 'fd/components/text_input_instance.html';
          };
```

Answer (score 7):

templateUrl property of component also takes a function. so you can try this,

```
angular.module('runtime')
  .component('textInput', {

      templateUrl: ['$configuration', function($configuration) {
        return $configuration.basepath + '.html'
      }],
      controller: [
          '$scope', '$element', 'focusInputGroup', 'configuration',
          function($scope, $element, focusInputGroup, configuration) {
```

Comment: Should be `templateUrl: [...]`, otherwise it will just print the HTML template file name as `template` is a string.

Comment: correct. i am used to use <component-name></component-name> .